# Sum values from Maps using streams and collect to List

Tags: java, java-stream

If I have a list of lists:

```
List<List<Map<String, Object>>> myList = new ArrayList<>();

List<Map<String, Object>> e1 = new ArrayList<>();
e1.add(new HashMap<String, Object>(){{put("test", 1);}});
e1.add(new HashMap<String, Object>(){{put("test", 6);}});

List<Map<String, Object>> e2 = new ArrayList<>();
e2.add(new HashMap<String, Object>(){{put("test", 9);}});
e2.add(new HashMap<String, Object>(){{put("test", 2);}});

myList.add(e1);
myList.add(e2);
```

I want be able to iterate over `myList` sum the ints in the inner lists (`e1` and `e2`) and return a list of the sums:

```
List<Integer> result = [7, 11]
```

Comment: also something like `myList.stream()
                .flatMapToInt(l -> l.stream()
                        .flatMap(l1 -> l1.values().stream())
                        .mapToInt(e -> (int) e))
                .boxed()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
List<Integer> result = myList.stream()
        .map(list -> list.stream()
                        .flatMapToInt(map -> map.values()
                                                .stream()
                                                .mapToInt(i -> (int) i))
                        .sum())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is  another alternative in a more global way **ernest_k** solution is better and elegant but may be this will help you to learn more about streams

```
    BinaryOperator<Object> accumulator = (a, b) -> Double.parseDouble("" + a) + Double.parseDouble("" + b);

    List sums = myList.stream().map((e) -> e.stream()
            .map((content) -> content.values().stream().reduce(0, accumulator)).reduce(0, accumulator))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println("sums \n"+sums);
```